# Creating a simple Dropdownlist in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a text box for taking in the values of a job role. However this is constrained to a certain number of roles on the database side of things. Therefore it would make more sense for me to use a dropdownlist which includes the valid roles only. I'm trying to set this up but have run into difficulties.

I placed the following code in my view:

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Roles)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Role)
</p>
```

and this in my model:

```
public List<string> Roles
    {
        get
        {
            return new {"Author","Underwriter" };
        }
    }
```

This won't compile though. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I wish there is in the .Net framework the ability to create `IEnumerable<T>` by simply calling `IEnumerable<T> result = { myT, myT2 };` instead of having to write `IEnumerable<T> result = new T[] { myT, myT2 }`. If the objects are of the same type, the type could even be inferred (`var` friendly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need 2 properties on your view model in order to create a drop down list: a scalar property which will hold the selected value and a collection property containing the list of available items that you want to be shown.

So as always you start by writing a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Role")]
    public string SelectedRole { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles 
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Author", Text = "Author" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Underwriter", Text = "Underwriter" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

then a controller action that will pass this model to the view:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        return Content("Thanks for selecting role: " + model.SelectedRole);
    }
}
```

and finally a corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRole)
    @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.SelectedRole, Model.Roles, "-- Role --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedRole)

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `List<string>` to the creational statement

```
public List<string> Roles
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string> {"Author","Underwriter" };
        }
    }
```